# Navigation drawer menu items synchronization from a web service

Tags: android, xml

I am developing a small Android app which gets data from a PHP web service and presents it in the widgets such as Buttons and Textviews. I am using Navigation drawer in my app as a menu. I spent a few hours of making a research about if it's possible to populate Navigation drawer menu items based on the PHP web service response? In other words - is it possible to create XML layouts using Java code in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to Drawer Navigation using code as well:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Name of your item");
```

Comment: then how do I:
1. create a new instance of fragment from there?
2. pass methods to it?

Comment: Why you want to create a new fragment? Make you you are using latest Navigation View implementation that was added in Design Support library: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html